# What Happened to Core Data Bindings?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I've been out of the loop for a while, but it used to be you could use Interface Builder to add an NSArrayController, set it's mode to Entity, and bind the managedObjectContext to the MOC of the AppDelegate. That doesn't seem to work anymore.

I've read through the documentation, (of course it's very possible I missed something) but I haven't yet found a way to bind my Array Controller to my Core Data stack. Somewhere along the line things got "simplified". What is the preferred way to get objects from Core Data to my NSTableView?

---

For more details, I currently have a fairly empty non-document project, no storyboards, with no modifications to the App Delegate, but I did add a property on my App Controller to access the MOC:

```c
@interface JBAppController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;

@end

@implementation JBAppController

...
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    return [[(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentContainer] viewContext];
}

...
```

I'll probably redo this once I understand what the bindings are missing, or if we aren't meant to use bindings anymore, however the right way to get the data to the tableview is.

Comment: When are the app controller and array controller created? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Both controllers are instantiated in the xib. I’m attempting to bind the managedObjectContext of my array controller to the app controller, or app delegate, but ctrl-dragging in IB from the array controllers bindings doesn’t give me anywhere to connect.

Comment: Dragging onto the property should work. Did you try the Bindings Inspector? Is the App Controller an object in the xib?

Comment: App Controller is an object in the xib, tried the Bindings inspector, but not sure that's doing anything if the Connections Inspector still shows no connection. Here's a minimal reproducible example: https://jonathanbuys.com/downloads/TestCoreDataProject.zip It's as simple as I could make it, just trying to ask what we are supposed to bind the NSArrayController to, or how to bind it now, or should we do it that way at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-drag:

Control-drag to the property, configure the binding and click on Connect.

[image]

Bindings Inspector:

Configure the binding and turn on the Bind to checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It accomplishes the same as using the bindings inspector to manually set the MOC. Is the MOC outlet in IB not used anymore?